# Not able to alter column to integer or boolean in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, alter

I tried to alter a column to integer type using the below query postgres.

```
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type integer using testing2::integer;
```

pm_user - table name
testing2 - column name

The above column would be any kind of data type eg: boolean, text, varchar(256).

It gives error as 'ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL"' I tried solutions as below based on the previous queries asked in this website but it is not working for me.

```
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type integer using (testing2::integer);                                   
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type integer;            
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type numeric using (testing2::numeric);         
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type numeric (10,2);
```

What is the actual problem? Where it 
points input as null? which one is taken as null? What solution I can provide. The same query works when I try to change as

```
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type text using testing2::text;  
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type varchar(256)using testing2::varchar(256);
```

It is also not working for boolean.

Comment: I need to set the default value for integer column as 0 post altering data type to integer. For that purpose, I used the query "alter table pm_user alter column testing2 set default 0;" The above functionality is required for changing the data type of the column dynamically via the application for the requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that your column contains the string literal `'NULL'` instead of a "real" null value. Something like this:

```
create table pm_user (testing2 varchar);
insert into pm_user (testing2) values ('NULL');
```

(Note the `'NULL'` - that is not the same as `NULL`)

So the expression to convert the string to a number must take care of that.

The following will convert a varchar column to integer. Any value in that column that is not a proper integer, will be changed to null:

```
alter table pm_user alter column testing2 type integer 
   using case when testing2 ~ '^[-+0-9]+$' then testing2::integer else null end;
```

`~` is Postgres' operator for a regular expressions. `testing2 ~ '^[0-9]+$'` tests if the column only contains numbers.

Comment: This query works but I checked the column and the data in the column is empty for all rows. Why does it shows 'null' then?

Comment: What I can do for boolean? Should I set to false or true as in the previous query?